# Replace variables in a mathematical expression using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a mathematical expression like following format.

```
var exp = $(x)+$(y)-tan($(z));
```

using this I get x,y,z in an array

```
var dArray = Regex.Split(str, @"[^a-z\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "").ToList();
```

But I am trying to remove '$()' from equation first and then want to replace x,y and z variables. For example

```
first --> x+y-tan(z)
second --> 5+6-tan(7)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Math.net](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/) something like this

```
var expression = Infix.ParseOrThrow("x+y-tan(z)")
var symbols = new Dictionary<string,FloatingPoint>
   {{ "x", 5 }, { "y", 6 }, { "z", 7 },};
Evaluate.Evaluate(symbols, expression).RealValue;
```

To get rid of the `$` sign, just do `"$...".TrimStart('$')`

Comment: How to remove '$()'?

Comment: the `()` jsut leave it doesn't influence and the `$` just `string.Replace` with an empty string

Comment: is there possible to add custom symbols like a1,a2 etc? When I tried to evaluate a1+ a2 using 'Infix.ParseOrThrow' it get error

Comment: No, sadly I think you can only have letters in the symbols

Answer (score 1):

How about the below regex replace code. It uses a capture group to obtain the letter inside $()

```
string exp = "$(x)+$(y)-tan($(z))";
string pattern =  @"\$\((\D)\)";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string newExp = rgx.Replace(exp, "$1");
newExp = newExp.Replace("x", "5").Replace("y", "6").Replace("z", "7");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple find `\$\(([^()]*)\)`
and replace `$1`

should remove the `$()` while preserving it's contents.

```
 \$\(
 ( [^()]* )                    # (1)
 \)
```